# Domain Driven Design: When to make an Aggregate Root?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, domain-driven-design, bdd

I'm attempting to implement DDD for the first time with a ASP.NET MVC project and I'm struggling with a few things.

I have 2 related entities, a Company and a Supplier. My initial thought was that Company was an aggregate root and that Supplier was a value object for Company. So I have a Repository for company and none for Supplier.

But as I have started to build out my app, I ended up needing separate list, create, and update forms for the Supplier. The list was easy I could call Company.Suppliers, and create was horrible I could do Company.Suppliers.Add(supplier), but update is giving me a headache. Since I need just one entity and I can't exactly stick it in memory between forms, I ended up needing to refetch the company and all of the suppliers and find the one I needed to bind to it and again to modified it and persist it back to the db.

I really just needed to do a GetOne if I had a repository for Supplier. I could add some work arounds by adding a GetOneSupplier to my Company or CompanyRepository, but that seems junky.

So, I'm really wondering if it's actually a Value Object, and not a full domain entity itself.

**tldr;**

Is needing separate list/create/update view/pages a sign that an entity should be it's own root?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Based on your terminology I assume you are performing DDD based on Eric Evans' book. It sounds like you have already identified a problem with your initial go at modeling and you are right on.

You mention you thought of supplier as a `Value Object`... I suggest it is not. A `Value Object` is something primarily identified by its properties. For example, the date "September 30th, 2009" is a value object. Why? Because all date instances with a different month/day/year combo are different dates. All date instances with the same month/day/year combo are considered identical. We would never argue over swapping my "September 30th, 2009" for yours because they are the same :-)

An `Entity` on the other hand is primarily identified by its "ID". For example, bank accounts have IDs - they all have account numbers. If there are two accounts at a bank, each with $500, if their account numbers are different, so are they. Their properties (in this example, their balance) do not identify them or imply equality. I bet we would argue over swapping bank accounts even if their balances were the same :-)

So, in your example, I would consider a supplier an `Entity`, as I would presume each supplier is primarily identified by its ID rather than its properties. My own company shares its name with two others in the world - yet we are not all interchangeable.

I think your suggestion that if you need views for CRUDing an object then it is an `Entity` probably holds true as a rule of thumb, but you should focus more on what makes one object different from others: properties or ID.

Now as far as `Aggregate Root`s go, you want to focus on the lifecycle and access control of the objects. Consider that I have a blog with many posts each with many comments - where is/are the `Aggregate Root`(s)? Let's start with comments. Does it make sense to have a comment without a post? Would you create a comment, then go find a post and attach it to it? If you delete a post, would you keep its comments around? I suggest a post is an `Aggregate Root` with one "leaf" - comments. Now consider the blog itself - its relationship with its posts is similar to that between posts and comments. It too in my opinion is an `Aggregate Root` with one "leaf" - posts.

So in your example, is there a strong relationship between company and supplier whereby if you delete a company (I know... you probably only have one instance of company) you would also delete its suppliers? If you delete "Starbucks" (a coffee company in the US) do all its coffee bean suppliers cease to exist? This all depends on your domain and application, but I suggest more than likely neither of your `Entities` are `Aggregate Roots`, or perhaps a better way to think about them is that they are Aggregate Roots each with no "leaves" (nothing to aggregate). In other words, company does not control access to or control the lifecycle of suppliers. It simply has a one-to-many relationship with suppliers (or perhaps many-to-many).

This brings us to `Repositories`. A `Repository` is for storing and retrieving `Aggregate Roots`. You have two (technically they are not aggregating anything but its easier than saying "repositories store aggregate roots or entities that are not leaves in an aggregate"), therefore you need two `Repositories`. One for company and one for suppliers.

I hope this helps. Perhaps Eric Evans lurks around here and will tell me where I deviated from  his paradigm.

Comment: Awesome answer! You helped validate what I was thinking and explained a lot more. Thank you so much!

I agree, there should be shared referenced to suppliers if they exist, but for the moment it will be user entered data with no way to validate that 2 suppliers are the same. That may change in the future as the system evolves, but for now that's the story. Thanks again!

Comment: I agree this is a great explanation, more helpful than what I typically find in the DDD mailing list!

Comment: Its from a book ([Domain Driven Design](http://www.amazon.com/Domain-Driven-Design-Tackling-Complexity-Software/dp/0321125215))!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a no-brainer to me - Supplier should have its own repository. If there is any logical possibility that an entity could exist independently in the model then it should be a root entity, otherwise you'll just end up refactoring later on anyway, which is redundant work.

Root entities are always more flexible than value objects, despite the extra implementation work up front. I find that value objects in a model become rarer over time as the model evolves, and entities that remain value objects were usually the ones that you could logically constrain that way from day one.

If companies share suppliers then having supplier as a root entity removes data redundancy as well, as you do not duplicate the supplier definition per company but share the reference instead, and the association between Company and Supplier can be bi-directional as well, which may yield more benefits.